# ClickOnce .application timing out with unknown subtype

Tags: iis, deployment, clickonce, mime-types

I have an existing ClickOnce application which began to time-out during initial installation on new clients.  I'm not sure if it is my IIS configuration or an external factor.  The Windows Server 2003 is configured with the ".application" MIME type of "application/x-ms-application" and this hasn't changed.  Directly running the .application file from a UNC share path works on the client machine.  Also, a client which already had the ClickOnce application installed can successfully update with a new version.  I must be overlooking something, so I thought I'd put it out there.  It really seems to point to the MIME type, however I even tried to add a wildcard "*" type of "octet/stream".

dgp

Timeout message

```
ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of http://{server}/{rootpath}/{appname}.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Downloading http://{server}/{rootpath}/{appname}.application did not succeed.
    + The operation has timed out
```

Details

```
OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [2/29/2012 8:25:22 AM] : Activation of http://{server}/{rootpath}/{appname}.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [2/29/2012 8:27:02 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
    - Downloading http://{server}/{rootpath}/{appname}.application did not succeed.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
```

After running WireShark I can confirm the MIME type on the client and see a successful HTTP 200.  Not sure about the iden-ralp conversation.

```
38  47.798381   {server IP} {client IP} HTTP    94  HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (application/x-ms-application)
39  47.798394   {client IP} {server IP} TCP 54  iden-ralp > http [ACK] Seq=2519 Ack=23684 Win=65535 Len=0
45  112.804146  {client IP} {server IP} TCP 54  iden-ralp > http [RST, ACK] Seq=2519 Ack=23684 Win=0 Len=0
```

Comment: I hate to have to ask but... did you restart the server?  If this is one of those servers that really shouldn't be restarted, try to stop and restart the IIS server.  I know this may not seem related but I have had odd errors crop up with my ClickOnce applications and restarting the IIS process has fixed the problem.  It may not help, but it can't hurt to try.

Comment: I did restart after attempting to add the "*" wildcard MIME type and once again after removing it.  Also, my IIS log shows a successful HTTP return code of 200 for the GET on the .application file to the client IP.  I'm thinking maybe the network guys tightened their filters.

Comment: If nothing on your side has changed, and if you are working by a corporate, firewalled infrastructure, I'd start asking IT questions about the changes that they made.  I've never seen this problem before, but I have experienced similar issues where network "big wigs" have decided to execute security measures that have brought our operations to a crippling hault.  All because they didn't think to first ask and verify if that would be okay. :/

Comment: We have had the same thing happen here.